# How do I find what is in a particular cell on the same row as another on based on a match?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I have the following query in Google Sheets:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A, 0)), "No Match", "Match on Row " & MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A, 0))
```

I want to return the value in column C of the matched row e.g. if there is a match on row 5 I want to return the value that is in C5.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) does.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:C, 3, FALSE)
```

searches for A2 in the *first* column of the range Sheet1!A:C, and returns the content of the 3rd column (relative to the range) in the row that matched.

In case of no match, an error #N/A is raised.

You can provide a custom error message by wrapping this in [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:C, 3, FALSE), "No match")
```